# UIGestureRecognizer firing twice?

Tags: iphone

I've set up a UITapGestureRecognizer on viewDidLoad of my view controller but somehow it fires the selector method twice for a single tap.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *g = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openInMapsApp:)] autorelease];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:g];
```

My method:

```
-(void)openInMapsApp:(UIGestureRecognizer*)g {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"This will open this location in the Maps application. Continue?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that this will happen only sometime?

Answer (score 19):

Gesture recognizers send action with different gesture state. So it's not a bug. Workaround is:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *g = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openInMapsApp:)] autorelease];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:g];
```

---

```
-(void)openInMapsApp:(UIGestureRecognizer*)g {
if(g.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    return;
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"This will open this location in the Maps application. Continue?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was having a double `UIAlertView` come up. As shown by Nicolas Rostov above, this worked for me.  Both the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and the `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` states created a new alertView when `[alertView show]` was used in the block. With //[alertView show] commented out, both of them still showed up on the console, but only one action took place.

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    return;
```

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm the same. I submitted a bug report to Apple with a sample project demonstrating the issue.

The temporary workaround I've found is to disable the UITapGestureRecognizer immediately before showing the Alert. Then, in the UIAlertView delegate method(s) you implement, re-enable it. This requires you to keep track of the GR somehow, but it seems like the most elegant solution for the time-being.

Using the sample code above:

```
-(void)openInMapsApp:(UIGestureRecognizer*)g {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                message:@"This will open this location in the Maps application. Continue?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    g.enabled = NO;
    self.activeGestureRecognizer = g;
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    self.activeGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.activeGestureRecognizer = nil;
}

- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    self.activeGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.activeGestureRecognizer = nil;
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue an an action sheet. This workaround fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This bug should be resolved as of iOS SDK 4.2. I was able to confirm the resolution from Apple.

Comment: I love the mountain of 10 years old bugs that Apple never fixes on their platforms.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I noticed the second event had the state UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled (whereas the first was UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded), so another workaround is to ignore the event in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved a similar issue. It turned out that I had **two tap gesture recognizers added to the view with the same call**. The way I found out is by NSLogging the gesture recognizer when the selector is being called.

In your place, I would check to make sure that you don't have two gesture recognizers - one coming from the storyboard, and another one created programmatically for example.

```
NSLog(@"recognizer: %@",[gestureRecognizer description]);
```

Comment: great tip. tnxx

Answer (score 2):

I added a timer to the view that checks to make sure the touch was at least half a second ago and ignore the second touch if it is too soon.

This is only a workaround though. I would still like to fix the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(g.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
//instead of if(g.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
return;
```

This will invoke the alertview immediately after the gesture event. for eg: if you use longtap event the alertview will be displayed once you take your finger off. But UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan state will be invoked automatically if the gesture is recognised automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I did this and worked:

first initialize a member on your handling object that stores the last swipe NSTimeInterval

```
-(id)initWithResourcePath:(NSString*)path  {

    if ([super init]) {
        //some code


        lastSwipe = 0;
    }
    return self;

}
```

Then add this code to your method

```
-(void)viewDetectedRightSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {


//touch being registered    
NSTimeInterval thisTouch = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

//if the last swipe is the first swipe, then there's nothing to do but the handling of a correct gesture
if(lastSwipe !=0) {
    // find out how much time has passed between gestures
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastTouch = thisTouch -lastSwipe ;

    NSLog(@"thisTouch = %f",thisTouch);
    NSLog(@"timeSinceLastTouch = %f",timeSinceLastTouch);
    if (timeSinceLastTouch<0.2f) {
        //return if this is an invalid touch
        return;
    } else {
        // register the timestamp if it is valid
        lastSwipe = thisTouch;
        NSLog(@"left");
    }

} 
// invalid gestures won't be registed because they won't get to this portion of code.
lastSwipe = thisTouch;
NSLog(@"left");
// rest of the handling code
}
```