# UIGestureRecognizer with NSTimer that never dies

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, nstimer

I'm trying to set up a "FastForward/Next" button in a media player that can be tapped to move to the next song or held to fast forward within the current song.  Mostly, it works: you can successfully fastforward and successfully move to the next song, but the thing is, the `NSTimer` that makes it work never invalidates, so once you start fastforwarding, you never stop.

I set up the gesture recognizers in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapFastForward = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(nextSong:)];
singleTapFastForward.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[_buttonNext addGestureRecognizer:singleTapFastForward];

_holdFastForward = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(startFastForward:)];
[_buttonNext  addGestureRecognizer:_holdFastForward];
[singleTapFastForward requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_holdFastForward];
```

and here is the meat of the function:

```
- (IBAction)startFastForward:(id)sender {
    _timerFastForward = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(executeFastForward) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)executeFastForward {
    [_avPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMake(CMTimeGetSeconds([_avPlayer currentTime]) + 10, 1)];
    if(_holdFastForward.state == 0) {
        [self endFastForward:self];
    }
}

- (IBAction)endFastForward:(id)sender {
    [_timerFastForward invalidate];
}
```

Here's the tricky part: when I set a breakpoint at the `if(_holdFastForward.state == 0)` line, it starts working as soon as I let go of the button (as it should), and it successfully calls the `endFastForward` method.  By my reckoning, that should kill the timer and end the whole cycle, but then `executeFastForward` gets called again, and then again and again.  The `invalidate` line just seems to do nothing (and there are no other points in my code that call `executeFastForward`).

Any ideas?  This seems like a simple thing, and if the `invalidate` line worked everything would be perfect.  I just don't know why `executeFastForward` continues to be called.  Is my `NSTimer` TRON's answer to the Highlander, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a LOT of experimentation (and being inspired by the `if` statement in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517402/1418688) to an unrelated but similar question) I finally found a solution: don't check for the end of the gesture in the `executeFastForward` method, but rather the `startFastForward` method.  Also, it turns out the `startFastForward` method was being called over and over, re-creating the timer, so the `if` statement also stops that by restricting the timer to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Here's the working code, for anyone who wants it:

```
- (IBAction)startFastForward:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _timerFastForward = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(executeFastForward) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    } else if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self endFastForward:self];
    }
}

- (void)executeFastForward {
    [_avPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMake(CMTimeGetSeconds([_avPlayer currentTime]) + 10, 1)];
}

- (IBAction)endFastForward:(id)sender {
    [_timerFastForward invalidate];
    _timerFastForward = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` takes selector that should take one parameter as `NSTimer *`, here is the cite from Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)

> The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

Try to change the signature of your `executeFastForward`  method like this:

```
-(void) executeFastForward:(NSTimer *)timer
```

than you can invalidate the timer passed as an argument, which will actually be the fired timer object

Comment: Didn't help.  :/  I did get a clue, though: after hooking up `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` (which worked perfectly using the same NSTimer method), I can safely say that it has something to do with the `UIGestureRecognizer` that is starting this whole thing.  Any ideas for why that would mess up the `invalidate` method?